# Custom Validation By Throwing Exceptions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, exception

I am validating models in ASP.NET MVC, and throwing a custom Exception that contains a list of those errors.  Is this a preferred, best practice, or should I return a strongly typed list of errors instead of using a throw new CustomException(List errors).  I catch these errors regardless in my OnException in the BaseController to handle an ajax request or post back.

Answer (score 5):

No. You should use `ModelState` to store your validation errors. Exceptions should only be used in exceptional cases.

`ModelState` has `IsValid` and will return `false` if there are any errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776396/validation-how-to-inject-a-model-state-wrapper-with-ninject

Comment: Can we do this even in an API controller?

Comment: @Worthy7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handle-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-web-api