# updated validation example for web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I tried the validation example code for web api on the latest mvc 4 download and I'm getting some errors.  Does anyone have an updated example of the ValidationActionFilter class.

Here's the original code

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute 
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context) 
    { 
        var modelState = context.ModelState; 
        if (!modelState.IsValid) 
        { 
            dynamic errors = new JsonObject(); 
            foreach (var key in modelState.Keys) 
            { 
                var state = modelState[key]; 
                if (state.Errors.Any()) 
                { 
                    errors[key] = state.Errors.First().ErrorMessage; 
                } 
            } 

            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage<JsonValue>(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I'm getting an error on HttpResponseMessage

```
The non-generic type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Also it looks like I need to add a Json reference, but should I be using JSON.net instead?  An example of this using Json.net?

Comment: Check more answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handling-modelstate-validation-with-asp-net-web-api/11724405#11724405

Comment: Check this blog post out: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-and-handling-modelstate-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpResponseMessage<T>` is from version beta, it no longer exists in the version release, use below instead:

```
 actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                              .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
```

Comment: also do you know how this code would be updated for Json.net since it looks like they removed System.Json

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey: for the release version, `System.Json` is no longer used, `Newtonsoft.Json` is used instead

Comment: for errors, what would I use instead of new JsonObject()?  Would it just be new Dictionary<string, string>() and the json serializer will automatically serialize the response somewhere else in the flow?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey: Ah I got it, you can use `JObject`

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey: remember adding `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`