# web api from body value is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have checked similar questions to this here:

[web-api POST body object always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741943/web-api-post-body-object-always-null)

This does not exactly match what is happening in my scenario.  I am making a request to my api with the following request header content-type:

```
Key Value
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

My request body then is a Response I get from another service which I cannot change

```
Response=SomeLongStringOfBAse64EncodedData
```

My Api Post Method which I can see gets hit by setting a breakpoint on it is as:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate([FromBody]string Response)
```

However Response string is always getting null value even though I see it in the request body which I cannot understand.

Comment: How are you calling `Authenticate`?

Comment: a page gets loaded in my website - it has a hidden form with a POST action on it.  The action on it is my Authenticate URL route and the the form also contains the Response Base 64 string.  I think the Request is being made ok as I hit the breakpoint - just cant figure out why the Request Body isnt binding to my parameter

Comment: @TheRiddler Please post how the call the `Authenticate` is made and the route for the action too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an action method like this

`public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate([FromBody]string Response)`,

you need to have the request body like this, for binding to work.

`=SomeLongStringOfBAse64EncodedData`

If you want to bind `Response=SomeLongStringOfBAse64EncodedData`, you will need to change the action method like this.

`public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(SomeClass response)`

and add a class

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The FromBody can be tricky, a few issues I have found in iOS, if your using RestKit - I had to post it as json with the single property being empty quotes. ''='value'. In Android, if you use Retrofit - then as long as you post it with @Body, the webapi will pick it up.

Comment: You don't need to prefix it with '=' sign if you use JSON.stringify(item);