# How to return invalid JSON message on POST using FromBody?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, frombodyattribute

I am creating an ASP.Net 5 application with MVC 6, using .Net 4.5.1. I have a POST method that uses a FromBody parameter to get the object automatically.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insert([FromBody]Agent agent)
{    
    try
    {
        var id = service.Insert(agent);
        return Ok(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return HttpBadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

This is just a proof a concept, I won't return only the id on success or the full exception on error.

When a valid JSON is sent everything works fine. However when an invalid JSON is sent, I get an exception during debug:

> Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character
>   was encountered: l. Path 'Name', line 2, position 20.

The problem is that after this error, the method is called normally, but with a null parameter, and the exception doesn't propagate.

I could check for null and return a generic message, but that is not as useful as the original message, which has important information, such as the tag name and position of the invalid character.

So I want to capture this exception and return it to the HTTP caller. How do I do that? Something like this:

```
{"error": "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: l. Path 'Name', line 2, position 20"}
```

I know I could capture and deserialize the JSON manually inside a try/catch block, but that is not acceptable for me. I want to do it and continue using FromBody, which I find very productive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default `JsonInputFormatter` will in fact return a null model upon encountering an error - but it will populate `ModelState` with all exceptions.

So you have access to all encountered errors by digging into `ModelState`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insert([FromBody]Agent agent)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ModelState
            .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors, (y, z) => z.Exception.Message);

        return BadRequest(errors);
    }

    // Model is valid, do stuff.
}
```

Output of above is an array of all exception messages, e.g.:

```
[
    "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: l. Path 'Name', line 2, position 20",
    "Another exception message..."
]
```

[JsonInputFormatter - Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L133)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thanks! =)

Comment: OMG! This will save me soo much time! TY.

Answer (score 7):

I found myself with exactly the same problem, but was able to find a different solution.
I will share my solution here as an alternative to @ypsilo0n's answer.

Instead of checking in every controller the `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` we can have this middleware filter:

```cs
public class FooFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var modelState = context.ModelState;

        if (modelState != null && modelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            // this class takes the model state and parses 
            // it into a dictionary with all the errors
            var errorModel = new SerializableError(modelState);

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the controller never gets called because this middleware runs before and ends the request. (read [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) for more information).

When we set a non-null `context.Result` it means "end the HTTP request here" (the docs) -- not very user friendly/intuitive if you ask me but OK (would expect a return value instead).

---

using .net core 1.1

Answer (score 0):

For .Net 6 using System.Text.Json (not Newtonsoft) when invalid JSON is passed, eg a large number in a Integer field, we get this trippy exception:

<sub>"title": "One or more validation errors occurred".
"status: 400,
"errors": [ "The dot field is required."]</sub>

[image]

---

I tried the `ActionFilterAttribute` and it didn't work; it doesn't get invoked. I even tried  `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute` and while its Constructor is called before the error; the `OnException()` method isn't invoked.

With little choice except to roll my own I made a custom `[FromBody]` Attribute we can use in our Controllers, replace `[FromBody]` with `[ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinder))]`:

```
ControllerMethod([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinder))] Dto dto)
```

The `catch (JsonException ex)` will only return one invalid property regardless if there's more, it doesn't support multiple. You have to fix them up one at a time. IMHO no invalid JSON should ever be sent, so while **we cater for it** there's no need to invest time on *Garbage In, Garbage Out*. If numeric values have their bounds enforced, dates are passed as strings and booleans as true/false then invalid JSON will never be a problem.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

// NOTE: When invalid JSON is passed the ASP.Net [FromBody] Attribute returns an ugly message,
// this JsonBinder allows us to intercept the input and return a more user friendly message.

public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // Get the request body stream
        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        using var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);

        // Read the request body as a string
        var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        try
        {
            // Deserialize the request body as a JSON object
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            };
            
            // This line will cause an Exception if the JSON is invalid.
            var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(content, bindingContext.ModelType, options);

            // Validate the deserialized object
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model!);
            if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(model!, validationContext, validationResults, true))
            {
                // If validation fails, add error messages to the ModelState
                foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage ?? string.Empty);
                }
            }

            // Set the deserialized object as the model for the binding context
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            // Rethrow the JsonException, this will trigger the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware's Try/Catch and we want
            // to show this inner exceptions detail indicating the first invalid property, instead of "the DTO failed to deserialize.".
            throw ex;

            // Or if there isn't an outer Try/Catch you can return the error:
            var error = new JsonValidationError
            {
                PropertyName = "myProperty",
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message
            };
            var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(error);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
    }
```