# How to log ASP.NET Core input JSON serialization errors

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

We have ASP.NET Core application which we use as a REST api. Methods use `[FromBody]MyClass param` as input. Problem is if the client sends an invalid JSON string the `input` value becomes null due to JSON serialization errors. Is there a way to log such errors?

Edit: I'm looking for application-wide solution not per-method..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 - how to return invalid JSON message on POST using FromBody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277427/asp-net-5-mvc-6-how-to-return-invalid-json-message-on-post-using-frombody)

Comment: @Kirk: This is not the same question. The linked question asks how to return json errors to the caller and the accepted answer is per-method basis solution. I'm looking to catch and log them application-wide.

Comment: Did you read the second, non-accepted answer that describes how to use a filter to do exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: @Kirk: I did not see that, my bad. I've solved what I'm looking for differently, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved this with adding an error handler in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
              options.SerializerSettings.Error = (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args) =>
              {
                    //Log args.ErrorContext.Error details...
              };
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but how do you log it when you inject LoggerFactoryManager.Init(_); in the same ConfigureServices method?

Comment: var logger = LoggerFactoryManager.GetLogger<JsonSerializerSettings>();
                            logger.LogWarning("Failed to deserialize JSON on input: " + args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);

Answer (score -1):

You can use an action filter to capture any model binding error (including deserialization errors).  You can pull the error from the ActionExecutingContext.

EDIT: To use this approach, You need to suppress the model state invalid filter because by default web api will automatically return a 400 if there is a binding error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.suppressmodelstateinvalidfilter#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-apibehavioroptions-suppressmodelstateinvalidfilter

```cs
    public class LogModelBindingErrorFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var messages = context.ModelState.Values
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                    .Where(x => x.Exception is JsonException)
                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, string.Join(", ", messages));
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Json deserialization error will happen before ActionFilters. Those are called after model binding. This will not be called. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters

Comment: @PekkaYlenius Yes, model binding happens before action filters, but the errors that occur during model binding are stored in ModelState so it can be inspected later. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245960/7810515