# Web API controller GET method executing successfully - But giving Internal server error(500) at client browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

When returning `null` value, following code in Web API controller executed successfully without any errors, while debugging it.
But in browser it gives Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error. Please see the attached error image.

```
[HttpGet("GetPreRegisteredPatientByMrn/{patientId}")]
public async Task<PreRegistrationPatientDetailsDto> GetPreRegisteredPatientByMrn(int patientId)
{
      try
      {
        return await _readService.GetPreRegisteredPatientByMrn(patientId);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        _logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
        throw;
      }
}
```

[image: StatusCode-500]

PS -
Earlier this code written in .netcore version 2.1.Later updated to .netcore 3.1 version. Internal server error 500 comes in .net core 3.1 version. it works fine with .netcore 2.1 version.

Comment: Looks like a serialization issue - Can you try this method - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956001/38024 and check what exception is throwing?

Comment: services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                options.SerializerSettings.Error = (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(args.ErrorContext.Error.StackTrace);
                };
            });

Comment: @Anuraj  ,  Since using .netcore 3.1 , my code is looks like above comment. But when  debugging breakpoint never hits into  that error handling code.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to know whats going on, but it could be failing to convert the dto to a json/xml object. Maybe you can catch the exception if you tinker with the exception settings and turn the CLR exception on.

[image]

Comment: I tried that. for that method also it is failing to catch the exception when debugging.