# How do I create a custom api parameter validation attribute which returns bad request on aspnet core 3?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, parameters

I have the following endpoint in my controller, and I would like to create a custom validation for attribute passed from query.

```
[ApiController]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/user")]
    public IActionResult GetUsersByLevel(
        [BindRequired, ValidLevelFromQuery(Name = "level")] string level)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My desired outcome is that I create a custom `FromQuery` attribute, which in this sample I describe as `ValidLevelFromQuery`. The custom attribute would check the value of `level` and would only accept `"A", "B", and "C"`, on any other value, the response to the client will be a `BadRequest`.

Currently I am doing the validation after I have read the value in the action. My goal is have this check earlier in the request pipeline.

I would like to avoid using `IValidatableObject` if possible.

Comment: You can create a custom attribute and have your logic there, and then add the attribute to your parameter, like BindRequired.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977418/validate-query-parameters-without-using-a-model-in-netcore-api/52977922 might be helpful

Comment: Thanks, managed to draw a solution based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ActionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters) to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/user")]
        [ValidLevelFromQuery]
        public IActionResult GetUsersByLevel(
           [BindRequired] string level)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

ValidLevelFromQuery method:

```
public class ValidLevelFromQueryAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates Level automaticaly
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("level"))
            {
                string[] allowedGroup = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
                if (!allowedGroup.Contains(context.ActionArguments["level"]))
                {
                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("The level is not allowed");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Found a solution based on Aspram's comments, which is exactly what you have answered. Thanks for taking the time to answer and will accept your answer so others can see it.