# MVC5/API2 CreateErrorResponse in custom ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

With MVC4 I was able to create and register a global action filter that would check the model state prior to the action's execution and return the serialized `ModelState` before any damage could be done.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
    }
}
```

However, with MVC5, I am having trouble finding `Request` and therefore `CreateErrorResponse`

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext nActionExecutingContext)
{
    if (!nActionExecutingContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        nActionExecutingContext.Result = // Where is Request.CreateErrorResponse ?
    }
}
```

I realize that I could create a custom response class to assign to `Result` but I'd rather use what's built-in if `CreateErrorResponse` is still available.

Any idea where I can find it relative to an `ActionExecutingContext` in MVC5 / Web API 2?

Comment: See this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handle-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently had the same problem and solved it using

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    }
}
```