# What is the purpose of BadRequest(ModelState)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

What is the utility of

```
protected internal virtual InvalidModelStateResult BadRequest(ModelStateDictionary modelState);
```

from `public abstract class ApiController`

I juts tried to us it for my Web API

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   var foo = BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

but nothing happens

Should I override it? And how because I can override 3 BadRequest method with different return result.

Comment: Use action filter like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handle-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-web-api/11724405#11724405

Comment: To make something happen, you're meant to `return BadRequest(...);`, just as you also might `return Ok(...);`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever. I just need to return the bad request. Now this bring me to another question. What type my API must return? object, HttpResponse that is not compatible with BadRequest that request an InvalidModelStateResult...

Comment: @B413, `BadRequest` inherits from `IHttpActionResult`. action should have that as its return type

Comment: @NKosi, And how do you deal with all my API that already return HttpResponseMessage? Is it wrong?

Comment: @B413, No it is not wrong. just different way of doing same thing. `BadRequest` and the others like it that are inherited from `IHttpActionResult` were added in a more recent version of the framework than `HttpResponseMessage` Under the hood they use it to create the response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21758615/196526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BadRequest` method returns `InvalidModelStateResult` which is `IHttpActionResult`.

So it should be something you return from action

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

When BadRequest is used then response has 400 status code set.