# Validate Model in Pipeline Instead of Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

All my controller methods have this as the first couple of lines:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Can I make this happen in the pipeline before a request gets to the controller?  That way I can assume that the model is valid for all requests.

I use stuff in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace to annotate my DTO classes.

Comment: You can handle by using global action filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handle-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-web-api/11724405#11724405

Comment: This does not work for asp.net core

Comment: Yes. So are you looking for some middleware options to validate instead of filters