# Return a list of errors with BadRequest (WebApi)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

As the title indicates all I'm trying to do is return a custom collection of errors if the "Model" is incomplete.

Whilst actively "SO'ing/Googling" I haven't found a solution to help with my problem.

I could of used "ModelState" but due to "Customisation", I'd like to do this manually.

Code as Follows:

**API Level**

```
// POST api/<controller>
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Order order)
{
    var modelResponse = new ModelResponse<Order>(order);
    if (order == null)
        return BadRequest("Unusable resource, object instance required.");

    //Check if all required properties contain values, if not, return response
    //with the details
    if (!modelResponse.IsModelValid())
        return this.PropertiesRequired(modelResponse.ModelErrors());

    try
    {
        await _orderService.AddAsync(order);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }
    finally
    {
        _orderService.Dispose();
    }

    return Ok("Order Successfully Processed.");
}
```

**Properties Required Action Result**

```
public List<string> Messages { get; private set; }
public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }

public PropertiesRequiredActionResult(List<string> message, 
    HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    this.Messages = message;
    this.Request = request;
}
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult(Execute());
}

public HttpResponseMessage Execute()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    response.Content = new ObjectContent()
        //new List<StringContent>(Messages); //Stuck here
    response.RequestMessage = Request;
    return response;
}
```

**Finding incomplete properties, based on a custom Attribute**

```
private T _obj;

public ModelResponse(T obj)
{
    _obj = obj;
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GetPropertyAttributes(PropertyInfo property)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> attribs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    // look for attributes that takes one constructor argument
    foreach (CustomAttributeData attribData in property.GetCustomAttributesData())
    {

        if (attribData.ConstructorArguments.Count == 1)
        {
            string typeName = attribData.Constructor.DeclaringType.Name;
            if (typeName.EndsWith("Attribute")) typeName = typeName.Substring(0, typeName.Length - 9);
            attribs[typeName] = attribData.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
        }

    }
    return attribs;
}
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties()
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(
            prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(APIAttribute)));

    return props;
}
public bool IsModelValid()
{
    var props = GetProperties();
    return props.Any(p => p != null);
}
public List<string> ModelErrors()
{
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var p in GetProperties())
        {

            object propertyValue = _obj.GetType()
                .GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(_obj, null);

            if (propertyValue == null)
            {
                errors.Add(p.Name + " - " + GetPropertyAttributes(p).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
        return errors;
}
```

**Sample of Attribute**

```
/// <summary>
/// The date and time when the order was created.
/// </summary>
[API(Required = "Order Created At Required")]
public DateTime Order_Created_At { get; set; }
```

So ignoring the two latter snippets, that was more to give a full process overview. I completely understand there are a few "out the box" techniques but I do enjoy crafting my own implementations.

To the point, Is it possible to return a list of errors with "BadRequest"?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom implementation of `IHttpActionResult` use the request to create the response and pass the model and status code.

```
public List<string> Messages { get; private set; }
public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }

public HttpResponseMessage Execute() {
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Messages);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, Thanks. This will also allow me to pass in a status code thus keeping it generic.

Answer (score 6):

You probably looking for using this method:

```
BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
```

The usage of it is something like this, the example is from [another question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698440/5160941) :

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Depending on the model errors, you get this result:

```
{
   Message: "The request is invalid."
   ModelState: {
       model.PropertyA: [
            "The PropertyA field is required."
       ],
       model.PropertyB: [
             "The PropertyB field is required."
       ]
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Whilst this is the correct answer and any future readers should use this approach. I'm looking to build my own implementation. Thus not using model state... All is working other than returning a "list" of errors. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Than you might want to use BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest(object error) as error is actually List<error>

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late from the day this post was made but just in case someone else has the same need.

I did it in this way:

```
public object GetModelStateErrors(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var state in modelState)
        {
            foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
            {
                errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        var response = new { errors = errors };

        return response;
    }
```

As you cand see, `GetModelStateErrors` is a function that returns a string array with the collection of errors you've got and receives the `ModelState` object to get those errors from it.

I implemented it like this:

`return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, GetModelStateErrors(ModelState))`

The response I get using Insomnia is:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "The Correo field is required.",
        "The Telefono field is required."
    ]
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: public object makes me sad