# Using Required and JsonRequired in ASP.NET Core Model Binding with JSON body

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, model-binding

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0, and I have a request object annotated like this:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleRequest([FromBody] MyRequest request)
{ /* ... */ }
```

I noticed an issue with model binding: When I send a request containing the header `Content-Type` set to `application/json` and a an empty body, as I expect, the `request` in my controller is `null` and `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`.

But when I have a body like this:

```
{
  "hello": "a-string-value!"
}
```

my `request` is NOT `null`, it has default values for everything, and `ModelState.IsValid` is `true`

This is happening of course while I'm missing all the `Required` properties, and the only existing one's name doesn't match a property there (even the type for this single parameter is `string`, which doesn't match any type on my model).

So in a way, those `Required` attributes seem to be working if there's nothing in my request, but they don't do anything if my request is not empty!

As I was preparing this question, I noticed that there's also a `JsonRequired` attribute, and it seems to take care of the properties being present.

So, what's the difference between `Required` and `JsonRequired`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For correct work of `Required` attribute, you should make the properties nullable:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    [Required]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? EndDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? StartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you send request with missing `Id`, `EndDateTimeUtc` or `StartDateTimeUtc`, corresponding field will be set to `null`, `ModelState.IsValid` will be set to `false` and `ModelState` will contain error(s) description, e.g. `The EndDateTimeUtc field is required.`

`JsonRequired` attribute is specific to JSON.Net. It plays during deserialization, while `Required` attribute (as other attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace) plays after model is deserialized, during model validation. If `JsonRequired` attribute is violated, the model will not be deserialized at all and corresponding action parameter will be set to `null`.

The main reason why you should prefer `Required` attribute over `JsonRequired` is that `JsonRequired` will not work for other content types (like XML). `Required` in its turn is universal since it's applied after the model is deserialized.

Comment: Thank you @CodeFuller. So, if I make everything nullable, then it seems to me that there will be additional things to take care of. For example, now my`EndDateTimeUtc` cannot directly call `AddMinutes` (as an example). Is it the proper way to do it? I mean with all those null checks that will be introduced in my controller code?

Comment: Yep, that complicates things a little. But if those properties aren't nullable, they will be left with their default values (e.g. `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`). I believe calling methods like `AddMinutes()` on such values will not make good. There are different ways to handle this. You could use null propagation, e.g. `EndDateTimeUtc?.AddMinutes()`. Another option, if such requests should be considered as invalid and result to http error, you could use action filter that checks model state (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724405/5740031) for details).

Comment: So, do you think, to avoid the complication, if I decide that my API is only going to support JSON, it's better to use `JsonRequired` to make things a little bit simpler?

Comment: No, I don't think it's a good way. You shouldn't have so tight coupling with Json.Net. It will also not save you from checking model parameters against `null` in each action. Consider adding action filter that just checks that model is valid (I've posted the link in above comment). It's really simple and clean solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just one thing: the filter example you provided, is it equivalent to doing this in the controller method: `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(ModelState); }`

Comment: Yes, both will result to the same `400 Bad Request` error.

Comment: Isn't this strange from a semantic point-of-view for the client?

Comment: @rumblefx0 I believe it's not only strange, but completely opposite in meaning. Required in english means MUST be provided. Nullable means: can or cannot be provided

Answer (score 2):

When you use `[FromBody]` as binding source, the Model properties will get default values and `[BindRequired]` will be ignored.
There is a related issue on ["Problems with Parameter Validation"](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7528).

In this case is better to use `[JsonRequired]` instead of `[BindRequired]` to enforce binding properties.

Note that `[JsonRequired]` affects serialization and deserialization both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the difficulty is that if you choose Required, the semantics for the client of the web request change incorrectly - i.e. you are saying you can pass in a null, when you really need a proper value.

Using JsonRequired sorts this, but this is provided by NewtonSoft, so stops working when you upgrade to .Net Core 3. This is because .Net Core 3 uses its own Json parser instead of NewtonSoft.