# JsonSerializationError not correctly handled by middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I encounter a very wierd error.

I have an Item with some properties that are JsonRequired.

When i try to call my route to get my Item when one property that is required is missing, my error is not automatically thrown as an error code 500 I get a 200 Ok instead.

Here is my route :

```
[HttpGet("{itemId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItemByIdAsync(long installationId, Guid itemId)
    {
        return await _itemService.GetItemByIdAsync(installationId, itemId);
    }
```

Here is my Item class :

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [JsonRequired]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [JsonRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my middleware :

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (NotFoundException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex, false);
        }
        catch (ConflictException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ex);
        }
        catch (BadRequestException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }

private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, HttpStatusCode httpCode, Exception exception, bool displayException = true)
{
        _logger.LogError(exception, $"Exception catched in middleware: {exception.Message}.");

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)httpCode;

        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ApiError(displayException ? exception.Message : string.Empty));

            return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload);
}
```

What I have tried : 
If I try to add this catch in the middleware

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
```

There is still the same result I don't get a 500 error.
I don't really understand why my response is not overrided to be a 500 error.
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does the 500 error say? Have you checked the body of the reply?

Comment: The problem is that I don't get a 500 error, the body is empty.
The middleware is not handling the JsonSerializationException.

Comment: On the outgoing reply? You assume that the list is empty, thus it should throw?

Comment: Or the item is null?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237767/using-required-and-jsonrequired-in-asp-net-core-model-binding-with-json-body) might solve your problem

Comment: One of the property of my device is null.
I am trying to reply with name = null for example !

Comment: No `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500BadRequest)]`?

Comment: [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)] maybe. 
But ProducesResponseType is only for the swagger.

Comment: I could not reproduce.Could you share you complete steps of calling the web api?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not show your `_itemService.GetItemByIdAsync`.It works well when I test with below code which has an 500 error.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> GetItemByIdAsync()
    {
        string json = @"{
          'id': '2f5135a7-977c-4b26-a4e2-74b9e374a75e',
          'name': null,

        }";

        Item x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);//throw 500 error using your Item model
        return x;
    }
```

You could also use `Required` property for JsonProperty like

```
[JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.Always)] //could not be null       
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The definition for it is:

```
    //
// Summary:
//     Indicating whether a property is required.
public enum Required
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The property is not required. The default state.
    Default = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The property must be defined in JSON but can be a null value.
    AllowNull = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The property must be defined in JSON and cannot be a null value.
    Always = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The property is not required but it cannot be a null value.
    DisallowNull = 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I will try what you are proposing.
But I don't get any error in my _itemService.GetItemById it returns an Item with a property id filled and a name at null.