# .NET Core [FromBody] annotation assigns default value instead of returning 400 error if value is missing

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, controller

I have created a controller method similar to

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<MyDTO> Post([FromBody] MyDTO myDTO)
{
    // do something with myDTO...
    Ok();
}
```

and MyDTO:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace.DTO
{
    public class MyDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public int someNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool someBool { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset someDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I send a post with a JSON body that doesn't have either defined, instead of returning a 400 or an exception of some sort, it just assigns default (falsy) values to them.

When I defined a List of another DTO class, it did return a 400 code.

How can I make the API return an error when certain required values are not provided instead of just using default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237767/using-required-and-jsonrequired-in-asp-net-core-model-binding-with-json-body).

I just had to make all the fields nullable and have a

```cs
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   // return 400
```

in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually control it. There's no other way.

Try something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<MyDTO> Post([FromBody] MyDTO myDTO)
{
    if(YourComprobation(myDto)){
       BadRequest();
    }
    Ok();
}
```

Comment: How do I stop FromBody from assigning default values to those fields?
Otherwise, there would be no difference between receiving a "false" or "0" and receiving nothing at all.

Comment: Also, is there a reason to use DataAnnotations if they don't automate the data validation process?

Comment: @Asghwor FromBody maps your json to the object you choose. Imagine you have `Post(string id, [FromBody] MyDTO myDTO)` what you are doing there is take the id variable from the route, for example, and the myDTO from the body. I don't understand what you want the FromBody mapper to do

Comment: I see. What's the purpose of the data annotations, exactly?
Also, how can I validate the JSON for missing values, wrong types, among other things?

Comment: @Asghwor the default value of a boolean is `false`, which passes validation `[Required]` of your tag. In the `YourComprobation` method that I mentioned you'll have to check for the "missing values" or create a custom tag that does that.

Comment: But how do I check for the missing value if it assigns a `false` value automatically?