# Autofac - Returning Concrete Type For Abstract Generic Type

Tags: c#, exception, autofac

I am trying to implement Exception Handling for my MVC Web Application using the [nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776396/validation-how-to-inject-a-model-state-wrapper-with-ninject/4851953#4851953) provided by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) as an answer to a StackOverFlow question.

At the bottom, the configuration needed for Ninject is provided so that the controller can be up and running. I'm using Autofac as the IoC container. Any help to to define the controller to instantiate the service class would be highly appreciated. Also, I'd be interestd to see an example on how the service class can be invoked from the controller if we are not using any IoC container.

UPDATE:
Following on Steven's example, these are the classes that I could write so far:

Business-Service-Layer:

```
namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public interface IValidationProvider
    {
        void Validate(object entity);
        void ValidateAll(IEnumerable entities);
    }
}   

namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public interface IValidator
    {
        IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(object entity);
    }
}

namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public class ValidationResult
    {
        public ValidationResult(string key, string message)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Message = message;
        }
        public string Key { get; private set; }
        public string Message { get; private set; }
    }
}

namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public abstract class Validator<T> : IValidator
    {
        IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidator.Validate(object entity)
        {
            if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            return this.Validate((T)entity);
        }

        protected abstract IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(T entity);
    }
}

namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public class ValidationProvider : IValidationProvider
    {
        private readonly Func<Type, IValidator> _validatorFactory;

        public ValidationProvider(Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory)
        {
            this._validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
        }

        public void Validate(object entity)
        {
            var results = this._validatorFactory(entity.GetType())
                .Validate(entity).ToArray();
            if (results.Length > 0) throw new ValidationException(results);
        }

        public void ValidateAll(IEnumerable entities)
        {
            var results = (
                from entity in entities.Cast<object>()
                let validator = this._validatorFactory(entity.GetType())
                from result in validator.Validate(entity)
                select result).ToArray();

            if (results.Length > 0) throw new ValidationException(results);
        }
    }
}


namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public sealed class NullValidator<T> : Validator<T>
    {
        protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(T entity)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();
        }
    }
}

namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public class ValidationException : Exception
    {
        public ValidationException(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> r)
            : base(GetFirstErrorMessage(r))
        {
            this.Errors =
                new ReadOnlyCollection<ValidationResult>(r.ToArray());
        }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<ValidationResult> Errors { get; private set; }

        private static string GetFirstErrorMessage(
            IEnumerable<ValidationResult> errors)
        {
            return errors.First().Message;
        }
    }   
}

namespace BusinessService.ValidationProviders
{
    public class NotificationValidator: Validator<NotificationViewModel>
    {
        protected override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(NotificationViewModel entity)
        {
            if (entity.PolicyNumber.Length == 0)
                yield return new ValidationResult("PolicyNumber",
                    "PolicyNumber is required.");

            if (entity.ReceivedBy.Length == 0)
                yield return new ValidationResult("ReceivedBy",
                    "ReceivedBy is required.");

            if (entity.ReceivedDate < DateTime.Now)
                yield return new ValidationResult("ReceivedDate",
                    "ReceivedDate cannot be earlier than the current date.");

        }
    }
}

namespace BusinessService
{
    public class NotificationService : INotificationService
    {
        private readonly IValidationProvider _validationProvider;

        public NotificationService(IValidationProvider validationProvider)
        {
            this._validationProvider = validationProvider;
        }

        public void CreateNotification(NotificationViewModel viewModel )
        {
            // Do validation here...
            this._validationProvider.Validate(viewModel);

            // Persist the record to the repository.
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModels-Layer:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class NotificationViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
        public string ReceivedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UI-Layer:

```
namespace ExceptionHandling.Controllers
{
    public class NotificationController : Controller
    {
        private INotificationService _service;
        private IValidationProvider _validationProvider;

        public NotificationController()
        {
            _validationProvider = null; // Need to instantiate this!
            this._service = new NotificationService(_validationProvider);
        }

        public NotificationController(INotificationService service)
        {
            // Need to instantiate service here..
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(NotificationViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this._service.CreateNotification(viewModel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Looking for some help to instantiate the NotificationService class from the controller. We are using Autofac for the IoC. It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction as to how to configure it for Autofac. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for liking my answer :-), but... I think you should update your question to be more specific, instead of pointing out to some code somewhere deep down in some stackoverflow answer. You should make it as easy as possible for anyone reading your question to understand what it is you want to know, without having to follow any links you provide.

Comment: @Steven I have copied the code as per your suggestion (been reluctant initially as it is the same as the example you had provided on the other SO answer!)

Comment: To be honest, my answer is not the best solution. If you can, prevent having IXxxService abstractions but use [command handlers](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) instead. This way you can decorate either the handlers or repositories directly with a decorator that adds validation.

Comment: I appreciate the robustness of 'Command Handlers'. As it might take more time to redevelop the current architecture we might stick to the existing pattern/layers in the short-term. Any help in this regard will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling to find a way of integrating Steven's solution with Autofac, I came across Patrick Desjardin's blog post:

[The three layers of validation](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/enterprise-asp-net-mvc-part-6-the-three-layers-of-validation) (Controller, Service & Repository).

I found it easy as you don't have to inject any Validation Providers. Also, it is easy to be integrated with any layer. Please make sure you read the follow up posts as well:

[How to validate model object with Asp.Net MVC correctly](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-validate-model-object-with-asp-net-mvc-correctly)

[Model validation and Entity Framework 4.3](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/model-validation-and-entity-framework-4-3)

Any opinions that compares both solutions would be much appreciated. Many thanks!