# Find class that implements generic interface with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

With Ninject you can register a binding like this:

```
Bind(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)).To(typeof(QueryHandler<,>));
```

But in my case I don't know the name of the actual class. All i know is that it implements a certain interface.

So for example, suppose I have the following:

```
public class CreatePageQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<CreatePage, string>
{
    public string Retrieve(CreatePage query)
    { ... }
}
```

There will be only one class that implements the interface with these gerenic params: `IQueryHandler<CreatePage, string>`

Is there a way with Ninject to dynamically get an instance of the class? Something like:

```
kernel.Get<IQueryHandler<CreatePage, string>>(); // returns instance of: CreatePageQueryHandler
```

---

**Please note:**

I don't want to manually `bind` this in the `RegisterServices` method. I'm looking for a dynamic way to get the instance of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Ninject contains a batch-registration API. You can use the following binding for instance:

```
kernel.Bind(
    x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Fully.Qualified.AssemblyName*")
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
    .BindBase()
);
```

Comment: I've installed `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions`. But the `bind` method still doesn't accept a lamda. Is there anything else I need for this?

Comment: tbh, I don't know. I copied the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284170/264697).

Answer (score 1):

With this Code you will get all types which implements IQueryHandler.

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => typeof(IQueryHandler).IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

After that you can register the types in Ninject or you can manually create a Instance from one of the Type:

```
var instance = (IQueryHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(types.First());
```

I did not test this Code, on .Net Core there is a different way to get all types from an assembly

Comment: Things get a bit more complicated when there is no non-generic `IQueryHandler`. In the question there only seems to be a generic `IQueryHandler<,>` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need Ninject convention extensions.

See https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions